# Ethereum hd wallet balance

Tags: wallets

Is any way to get a summary balance of ethereum hd wallet?

For example, I generated hd wallet and a lot of derived addresses (bip44). Made few transactions on these addresses and wanna know summary balance of these addreses.

Or give me advice how to receive payments on my site without 3rd parties.

Comment: This is two questions in one. I suggest you edit the question title to be more descriptive and open another question or research how to accept ether payments on eCommerce site.

Answer (score 1):

> Is any way to get a summary balance of ethereum hd wallet?

You can get all your addresses from XPUB which you have generated using BIP44 and get the balance of each of them using Geth, Parity or Eherscan API.

> Or give me advice how to receive payments on my site without 3rd parties.

You could buy cold wallet like Trezor or install some software wallet like Jaxx or Exodus and let them track your balance for you. The only problem I see there is [gap limit](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki#Address_gap_limit). Since you are going to use a lot of addresses maybe it is easier to assign id to each order, calculate the according address and check only one account balance when it is necessary instead of hundreds/thousands.

According to [BIP44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki) you may create an address by doing following derivations:
**m / purpose' / coin_type' / account' / change / address_index**
where address_index might be an order id. For example m/44'/60'/0'/0/100 would be an address for order #100.

Comment: Could you describe what kind of id do you mention? Is your suggestion using one address? But how to determine which user payment was made.

Comment: I suggest using one address per order. My guess that the easiest way to determine which user payment was made is to check all open orders (which may expire in a day or two). Also added an example to the answer.